# get variable from another function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to ask about how to get data from variables that are in other functions but still in the same controller....

this is the function, where the variable will be sent named $whs

```
function deliver($whs_id)
{
  $whs = $whs_id; // here is variable to pass

  $this->cart->destroy();
  $this->template->set_title('Package');
  $this->breadcrumbs->push('Package', '/Package');
  $this->breadcrumbs->push('Create Package', '/pacakge/index');


 $data['item'] = $this->MY_Model->join2_where('box_stock','product_code','box_product','product_code','whs_id',$whs_id)->result();
 $this->template->load('templates/Template', $this->folder.'/item', $data);

}

function save()
{
    $whs2 =$whs; // i will get data in here

        // judul halaman
  $this->template->set_title('Package');
        // Breadcrumbs
  $this->breadcrumbs->push('Package', 'package');
  $this->breadcrumbs->push('Save', '/package/save');
        // JS Init
  $js_init =  "";


  }
```

how can I get the data that is in another function in the same controller ?

Comment: Where do you call save() and deliver() I think you need to return it from deliver and pass it to save if you don't want to use global variables

Comment: Set it into session, you cant call if from another method as it won't be saved across requests.

Comment: I will send it from deliver () to save (), maybe I will try it using a session..
thanks

Comment: use session it worked !
thanks...